# Emailing Values from Array

Tags: php, arrays, email

I am new to PHP and am having an issue when it comes to emailing the data from html form fields that are arrays. I am having no problems inserting each of the array values into a MySQL database, I just get blanks when trying to email the array values.

In the email $school, $first_name and $title are not returning any array values. Please help, thank you.

```
   <?php

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
$date = date("m/d/y", time());
$referee = $_POST['referee'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$gamedate = $_POST['gamedate'];
$level = $_POST['level'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$away = $_POST['away'];
$title = $_POST['title'][$i];
$person = $_POST['person'][$i];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'][$i];
$jersey = $_POST['jersey'][$i];
$school = $_POST['school'][$i];
$reason = $_POST['reason'][$i];
$notes = $_POST['notes'][$i];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];


$result = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `soccercard` (date, referee, email_address, phone, gamedate, level, home, away, title, person, first_name, jersey, school, reason,  notes, checkbox)
    VALUES ('$date', '$referee', '$email_address', '$phone', '$gamedate', '$level', '$home', '$away', '$title', '$person', '$first_name', '$jersey', '$school', '$reason', '$notes', '$checkbox');
");

}

?>

<?php
if ($title = Red)
$to = "myemail@address.com";
$subject = "Soccer Card Report Form";
$message = ("A red card was submitted by '$referee' for the '$home' vs '$away' '$level'  game. $school $first_name was issued a $title card for $reason ");
$from = "myemail@address.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: change if($title == 'Red')

Comment: Before you go further, I'd recommend learning about indentation. It will help you spot your problems. Your `if` statement doesn't have any braces, and so I think it's either not doing anything or only applying to the line starting with `$to =...`. Also, learn about input sanitization. Your INSERT statement is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: Your variables in an loop 'for', so put your mailing code into the loop.

Comment: Also, it seems like you're mixing some things that should be inside the `for` loop (i.e. anything ending in `[$i]`) and things that shouldn't (i.e. everything else). Maybe that will at least get you closer.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

Change code as

```
   <?php

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
$date = date("m/d/y", time());
$referee = $_POST['referee'];
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$gamedate = $_POST['gamedate'];
$level = $_POST['level'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$away = $_POST['away'];
$title = $_POST['title'][$i];
$person = $_POST['person'][$i];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'][$i];
$jersey = $_POST['jersey'][$i];
$school = $_POST['school'][$i];
$reason = $_POST['reason'][$i];
$notes = $_POST['notes'][$i];
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];


$result = mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO `soccercard` (date, referee, email_address, phone, gamedate, level, home, away, title, person, first_name, jersey, school, reason,  notes, checkbox)
    VALUES ('$date', '$referee', '$email_address', '$phone', '$gamedate', '$level', '$home', '$away', '$title', '$person', '$first_name', '$jersey', '$school', '$reason', '$notes', '$checkbox');
");
if ($title == 'Red'):
$to = "myemail@address.com";
$subject = "Soccer Card Report Form";
$message = ("A red card was submitted by '$referee' for the '$home' vs '$away' '$level'  game. $school $first_name was issued a $title card for $reason ");
$from = "myemail@address.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
endif;
} //end of for loop

?>
```

Put title condition into for loop

Comment: Missed the `if` indentation